# Pac file does not work globally on Windows10

Tags: proxy, windows-10, pac

I have a socks5 server in 192.168.1.100, and my pac file looks like this:

```js
var proxy = "SOCKS5 192.168.1.100:1080; SOCKS 192.168.1.100:1080; DIRECT;";

function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return proxy;
}
```

I set this pac file on Windows10 system proxy setting. But it seems just the Edge and Chrome work well and other apps such as cmd.exe does not. In other words, the proxy setting doesn't work globally. How can I force all apps using this proxy instead of installing a third-party software like proxyfier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Winfoom](https://github.com/ecovaci/winfoom), it has support for PAC files.